# Is it possible to add target method for the delete key on the number pad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am using number pad for my `UITextField's`.

I have set the delegate for my textfields.

I used the required `delegate` methods to handle the different events.

But I am unable to capture the event when user taps on **`x`** mark on number pad when a `textfield` `hasBecomeFirstResponder` and there are no characters entered in a `textfield`.

However, I can get the  delete event when user pressed any character(*or when there is atleast one character present in the textfield*) and then press on delete key.

I set the keypad type as number pad in `storyboard`.

Delegate is set in both storyboard and also in code.

Here is the code if you want to have a look:

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

          if ([string length]==0) {
                NSLog(@"deleted");
                return YES;
            }

}
```

I think the above method should get hit whenever the I press any key on keyboard. But in my case, this method is not hit when I press the delete key when the textfield is empty.

**My question is:**
I am looking for a way to detect press on delete key in an efficient way. I don't want to add a button on top of the delete button. As one answer suggested to add a button to the delete key.

Is it possible to add the target method to the delete key,so that whenever 
I press delete key, that method would get hit?
(Or)
Is is possible to get a delete key event when there are no characters in a textfield and when the textfield has become the first responder?

> I want to know because, I have four textfields placed in a horizontal
>   stack view. When the user enters one character in first textfield, I
>   am making the second text field as first responder,and the user enters
>   the text on second textfield.
>
> And the same way, I want to make the other textfield become first
>   responder, when the user press delete key.Please note that, when I want to move back to other textfield by pressing the delete key, there will be no characters entered in the current textfield.And I am unable to detect delete key event when the textfield is empty.

[image]

Comment: ooh,, I tried by searching with "detect delete key when text filed is first responder"... I didnt try the empty keyword :P . I should really have shown some research effort!!! @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show either a space or a digit.

Comment: so you are saying to put a space when the textfield has become first responder ?

Comment: How does this answer question about whether you can detect the delete key on an empty text field?

Comment: @rmaddy It's a pragmatic solution, not a theoretical answer. What you point at as duplicate isn't very helpful.

Comment: what if I want to enter a character ? Do I need to delete the space and replace it with new character ? If not, the entered character will be in a different position. I am showing only the first character to the user in the textfield.

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, you need just a little bit of logic to remove the space and replace it with the character typed, and vice versa when the user taps delete.